# openssl java to c++ read int issue

Tags: java, c++, linux, openssl

I am using c++ ssl socket server(32 bit linux) & java based ssl client(windows 64bit).
SSL Handshake is sucess.
When i send string data from Java client to C++ Server able to receive & display.
When i send int data from Java client to c++ Server ,different data i am receiving

Java send source:

```
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
osw.writeInt(1000);
osw.flush();
```

C++ readInt source:

```
unsigned int result =0;
int byteRead = SSL_read(m_ssl, &result, sizeof(int));
unsigned int rxdInt = htonl(result);
```

c++ side ,when i print byte by byte for 
bytes read : 1

```
Expected: e8 03 00 00 
received : 00 00 00 00 
after htonl: 00 00 00 00
```

With below code ,writing as bytes ,its working with c++

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(4); 
bb.putInt(1000); 

DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
dos.write(bb.array());
dos.flush();
```

Without SSL writeInt is working with c++
with SSL writeInt not working
with SSL ,writing int as bytes working.
Why writeInt behavior is different in SSL case?

Comment: You might consider using Google's [`Protocol Buffers`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/). They will make it a lot easier to use messages with TLS. You won't have to worry about wire formats and presentation.

Comment: Since your meaning-destroying edit your code no longer compiles. The variant with `ByteBuffer` is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a `Writer` for binary data? You should be using `DataOutputStream.writeInt()`.

And then of course this:

```
unsigned int rxdInt = htonl(result);
```

should be this:

```
unsigned int rxdInt = ntohl(result);
```

And you're ignoring the value returned by `SSL_read()`, which could have been -1, zero, or less than 4.

Comment: tried with DataOutputStream also same issue DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
   dos.writeInt(1000);